# SharePoint List column limit, item doen't letting me edit list item

Tags: sharepoint-server

I have a list having 27 single line text columns, 7 multi line text columns, 7 Date and Time columns and 5 Person or Group columns. I was really wondering why I am unable to edit or save people picker value or multi line text columns values.

I know it doesn't exceeded row size. But I really couldn't understand why it is not letting me edit those columns.

Comment: Which version of SharePoint are you using?

Comment: In which view you are edit these columns? Can you provide us a screenshot what's happen?